# Increase xml:id with 1 find/replace with notepad++

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

a simple but short question. I am using notepad++ for my xml sheet. Heres is an example structure.

```
<category xml:id="S0078">
   <catDesc>
     <term>Test</term>
   </catDesc>
</category>
<category xml:id="S0079">
   <catDesc>
     <term>Test</term>
   </catDesc>
</category>
```

My question is how can i increase the id from S0078 to S300 by one with an simple search and replace command. I tried to use regular expression. but this was not working. Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: You cannot achieve that with pure regex anywhere I know. You  can use a PythonScript to replace the numbers you need. Just get a working version and write a `rereplace` piece of code.

Comment: are you trying to increase all S0078 ids to S300?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an XML aware tool to modify XML. For example, in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), you can do

```
open file.xml ;
for my $id in //category[
    (@xml:id | preceding-sibling::category/@xml:id) = 'S0078'
][
    (@xml:id | following-sibling::category/@xml:id) = 'S0300'
]/@xml:id
    set $id/. { $id->value =~ s/([0-9]+)/$1+1/er } ;
save :b ;
```